# I want to exclude one page from my `IndexedStack`

Tags: flutter, dart, material-design

I have a Homepage with a Navigation bar with 3 buttons every buttons have assigned a indexed screen but i want to exclude one and i don't know how.

```
final screens = [
    const ShopPage(),
    const CodeScanner(),
    const ShopListPage(),
  ];
```

The body of my `Scaffold`

```
body: IndexedStack(
        index: index,
        children: screens,
      ),
```

The one that i want to exclude is the `CodeScanner()`

Answer (score 0):

**Note:**
**Don’t use a bottom navigation bar for fewer than three destinations (use tabs instead).**

**Bottom navigation**

**Usage**

Bottom navigation bars display three to five destinations at the bottom of a screen. Each destination is represented by an icon and an optional text label. When a bottom navigation icon is tapped, the user is taken to the top-level navigation destination associated with that icon.

**When to use**

Bottom navigation should be used for:

- Top-level destinations that need to be accessible from anywhere in the app
- Three to five destinations
- Mobile or tablet only

**Bottom navigation shouldn’t be used for:**

- Single tasks, such as viewing a single email
- User preferences or settings

You can study this guide https://material.io/components/bottom-navigation#usage

Comment: This doesn't help at all, I'm using 3 destination one of them is a QR scanner, i want to kill that process when is not focused so the scan is not active all the time but without killing the others. that's all what i want to do.